# Javascript onclick button does not work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im writing a chrome plug-in based on facebook. However, the button I create cannot load the posttoDB function.  Where should I put the posttoDB function? I tried to put it in the a_facebook class and outside the class, both do not work.

What confuses me is that if I use chrome develop tool and type the following, it works!

```
  function posttoDB(i,index)
{
     alert(i);

}
```

can anyone tell me where should I put this onclick function and what the format is the function supposed to be?

```
var a_facebook = {

wall_length: 0,
profile_length: 0,

listener_func: null,
u1: null,
    array:null,
lang: {
post_placeholder: 'Type your anonymous post...',
    post_add: 'Send'
},

create: function(){

    this.initPage();
    //myFunction(1,2);

},

 initPage: function(){



    var i=0;

    clearInterval(a_facebook.listener_func);
    this.listener_fu=setInterval(function(){

        elements=document.getElementsByClassName("_5jmm _5pat _5uch");
            select_text="";
        for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
            select_text+="<option value=>";
            //select_text+="\"+"\">";
            select_text+=array[i];
            select_text+="</option>";

            }

        for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        var exist_name="submit"+i;
        var exist_button = document.getElementById(exist_name);
        if (exist_button!=null)
        continue;
 var  a=elements[i].getElementsByClassName("uiUfi UFIContainer _5pc9");

 if(a.length!=0)
     {

        var button_id="submit"+i;
        var button=document.getElementById(button_id);


        mydata=JSON.parse(elements[i].dataset['ft']);
        var post_id=mydata['mf_story_key'];

        var button_text="<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"posttoDB(";
        button_text+=i;
        button_text+=",";
        button_text+=post_id;
        button_text+=")\" id= \"";

        button_text+=button_id;
        button_text+="\">send</button>";

        if(button==null)
        a[0].innerHTML+=button_text;
     }
     }

        }                         
        ,1000);
},




posttoDB: function(index,post_id)
{
     alert(i);

}




};




a_facebook.create();
```

Comment: Have you tried instead of `.innerHTML+=button_text` collect HTML in advance in a string variable and then do a `.innerHTML = variable` ?